# How to count from an already distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count total from distinct, is that possible?

if it possible, help me with my sql query..

there is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT `agentName`, date_format(`dateTransaction`, '%d-%m-%Y') as date, 
time(`dateTransaction`) as time, `product`, `msisdn`, `productKode` as denom, 
`responFlag` as status, `col7` as `serial` 
FROM `transaksi`
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: i want just know how to count

Comment: What do you want to count? Usually you’d want to count the number of agents or count of product.

Comment: count all distint columns

Comment: How about adding `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `agentname`)`

Comment: All distinct column or any specific columns distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below `SQL` query to get `COUNT` of all `DISTINCT` records.

```
;WITH CTE AS( SELECT DISTINCT `agentName`, date_format(`dateTransaction`, '%d-%m-%Y') as date, 
time(`dateTransaction`) as time, `product`, `msisdn`, `productKode` as denom, `responFlag` as status, `col7` as `serial` FROM `transaksi`) 

SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT agentName, 
                      date_format(`dateTransaction`, '%d-%m-%Y')
                      time(`dateTransaction`,
                      `product`, `msisdn`, `productKode`,
                      `responFlag`, `col7`
            )
FROM `transaksi`;
```